# Unable to get Sharepoint Online data Web data source for Power BI

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi, datasource

What I wanted to do is to get the data for Power BI from web datasource. The excel data was uploaded in sharepoint online as document and then I copied link for url data source on the power BI side. It was working perfectly few days ago. But now whenever I want to retrieve data from web it always says "

> DataSource.error

> web browsercontents currently supports only anonymous credentials

[image]

Even if I clear the global permission through File>Options and Settings>Data source Settings>Global Permission>Clear All Permission, the results is still unable to get the data from web source. What could go wrong?
Any suggesiont?I have been 3 days stuck in this problem and unable to solve it until now.

Appreciate for your help.
Best

Comment: the problem persists several days, but mysteriously solved after updating the power BI

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution, What I pasted once was the link with the string after .xlsx extension, it supposed to work without one.
For example

```
https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/yourexcelfilename.xlsx
```